# Add Static Method to Sequelize Model Abstract Class with Typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

When working with Sequelize, I found it helpful to add static methods to all `Model`s. In Javascript I would simply assign the method in the following way:

```
const { Model } = require('sequelize)

Model.someStaticMethod = () => {}
```

However, in Typescript, this will cause an error as `someStaticMethod` is not defined on the abstract class `Model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get around this, you can create variables within a given namespace, thereby allowing you to augment the class and add static methods.

```
// types/sequelize/index.d.ts

import 'sequelize'

declare module 'sequelize' {
  namespace Model {
    let someStaticMethod : function // You can import the actual function definition here.
  }
}
```

Now when assigning `Model.someStaticMethod = () => {}`, Typescript will no longer throw an error.

Hope this helps someone out!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { MyHero, Hero } = require("../models/index.js");

class MyHeroesController {
    static async addHeroToMyHeroes(req, res, next) {
        try {
            const { heroId } = req.params;

            const myHero = await MyHero.findByPk(heroId);

            if (!myHero) {
                throw { name: "NotFound" };
            }

            const { UserId, status, match } = req.body

            const myHeroes = await MyHero.create({
                UserId,
                HeroId: +heroId,
                status,
                match
            });

            res.status(201).json({
                id: myHeroes.id,
                UserId: myHeroes.UserId,
                HeroId: heroId,
                status: myHeroes.status,
                match: myHeroes.match
            });
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    }
```